# I want to create a shared folder with a compilation data

Tags: vue.js, docker-compose, vite

I have created a docker-compose, all containers are okey but i want to create a shared folder, which it have compile data of vue. I thought that if I created a shared folder and then, I run commands to compile and shared folder contains compile date but I was wrong.

If someone can help me, i'm starting to learn docker and my english level is bad, but i hope that someone can help me.

if this can be done without using a better Dockerfile

My docker-compose:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${PG_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${PG_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${PG_DB}
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
  vue:
    image: node:14-alpine
    volumes:
      - ./frontend/adm:/app
      - dist:/app/dist
    working_dir: /app
    command: npm install && npm run build

  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.19
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - ./config/virtualhosts/:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - dist:/usr/share/nginx/html
    depends_on:
      - db
      - vue
  web:
    build: ./backend
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/app
    command: python app/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db

  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: ${PG_ADMIN_EMAIL}
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: ${PG_ADMIN_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
    links:
      - "db:pgsql-server"

volumes:
  postgres-data:
  dist:
```

Comment: Your English looks fine :D. Which volume do you want to be shared?

Comment: i want to shared dist, which its in vue contaner because its compiled there